# What is the firewall rule to restrict access to external web api calls running on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, firewall, aws-sdk

I am new on AWS. I've been hosting an ASP.NET Web API on an AWS EC2 instance. I would like to access this web api securely through AWS API Gateway. I configured the AWS API gateway service successfully, however EC2 instance accepts and responses external api requests which are coming directly from the internet.

My web api should only accept and response aws api gateway requests.

What is the correct firewall rule(s) in security group of my EC2 instance? Or do I need to create a policy in AWS IAM user.

This configuration shouldn't be restrict aws internal traffic in order to allow access aws api gateway requests.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You need to assign you EC2 instance under a security group. And configure the security group with inbound rules. Which will allow you to white list  IP range, port, protocol etc.